# Calls to a COM Server succeed under administrator account but fail under SYSTEM account

Tags: windows, com

I am trying to query some data from a COM server (actually the Motorola MeshAPI), but it fails to initialize. Using the code snippet below, I get successful data when running on the command line as Administrator, but my actual program using this code runs as a service under the SYSTEM account. Using "psexec -i -s cmd.exe" I ran the snippet under the SYSTEM account, and I get the same errors I saw with the service.

It is the CreateInstance() call that fails, with an error message "Server execution failed" and error code 2148007941 (0x80080005).
Under the Windows Event Viewer, in the System pane I see errors with source "DCOM", event ID 10010, and description "The server {....GUID} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout."

I've tried the tips from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157331 , but I haven't found anything helpful in solving this.

What would cause this to work under Administrator but fail under SYSTEM, and how can I get it to work when running under SYSTEM?

```
HRESULT hr=S_OK;
USHORT nLinkResistance;
if (!m_MeshNetInitialised)
{
    hr = m_pApiCardInterface.CreateInstance("MeshAPI.MeshNet");// mea interface smart pointer 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        m_MeshNetInitialised = true;
    }
}
if (m_MeshNetInitialised)
{
    hr = m_pApiCardInterface->GetIAPLinkResistance(&nLinkResistance);   
    if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
    {
        l_retval = nLinkResistance;
    }
    else
    {
        std::wcout << L"Error getting IAPLinkResistance" << std::endl;
    }
}
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    _com_error err(hr);
    std::wcout << err.ErrorMessage();
}
```

Comment: You should ask the vendor (Motorola). SYSTEM (LocalSystem?) can't do network connection for example, so if the COM Server attempts to use some network server, it will never be able to work under LocalSystem.

Comment: Look at the activation, access and identity setting for the "MeshAPI.MeshNet" COM object under DCOM config under Component Services control panel applet. If the component fails to run under system context then via the DCOM configuration you would be able to make it run under a different security context.